# Compile typescript code as well as dependent libraries

Tags: node.js, typescript

So we have a internal tool at work that takes our service model definitions, and generates a typescript client. However this generated client spits out a file that exports like this

```
export * from './client';
```

My node service complains when I try to import this, since it only supports commonjs imports. Is there any way to get my tsc compiler to transpile that library into a recognizable format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `module` compiler option in a tsconfig.json file to set the desired module output to commonjs:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

`tsc` will automatically find a tsconfig file in the current working directory, or you can specify a path to one using the `--project` argument:

`tsc --project ./path/to/tsconfig.json`

More about tsconfigs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: So I have that set but it does not do anything for dependencies in my node_modules/ folder. Maybe I could just copy the library over during build time and treat it as source code

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Do you not have control of the module in node_modules?

Comment: It is impoted from a another repo. Changing that code would not really be feasible right now. Unless I forked the code

Comment: Are you bundling your code with something? E.g. webpack.